EventHandler NRT annotation not recognized in *.designer.cs
Since NRT annotations of System.EventHandler the sender has to be nullable.
If I define an event handler without correct sender declaration it will force an CS8622 error at event handler registration.
The problem is that this error is not reported if the registration is done in *.designer.cs.
Example:
Form.designer.cs
btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(OnBtnClick); // No error is reported.

Form.cs
private void OnBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
}

// somewhere else in that file
btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(OnBtnClick); // reports CS8622

Our .editorconfig does not contain any entries according *.designer.cs-files or any settings for CS8622.
How do I enforce the compiler to report CS8622 even for *.designer.cs-files?
